# Print from array of strings in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

I have written the following program:

```
char name[100], firstDigits[13], cards[5000][16];

srand(1019336);
int i, j;
char c = '0';
for(i=0;i<13;i++){
    c = '0' + (rand() % 43);
    while(c > 57 && c < 65){
        c = '0' + (rand() % 43);
    }
    firstDigits[i] = c;

}
printf("%s \n", firstDigits);
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    for(j=0;j<13;j++){
        cards[i][j] = firstDigits[j];
    }
}
for(i=0;i<5;i++){

    for(j=13;j<16;j++){
        c = '0' + (rand() % 43);
        while(c > 57 && c < 65){
            c = '0' + (rand() % 43);
        }
        cards[i][j] = c;
    }
}

printf("%s \n", cards[1]);
```

The first loop generates a string of 13 characters which are from 0-9 and A-Z.
Then I want to generate an array of 5000 strings where each string's first 13 'letters' are that of firstDigits[13]. The problem is that when I try to print one of those strings like above I get as output all of the strings in the array! Why is this happening?

Comment: There are at least a few errors there. I am unsure of what exactly you are trying to do, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C strings must be null terminated. Printf will output chars until it hits a null. After you finish generating your random string add '\0' to the end. Of course you'll have to increase you array size by 1 to accommodate it.

Answer (score 2):

The `%s` format specifier is only for strings. It's not for arrays of characters. How would it know how many characters to print?

You can use `%.13s` to print 13 characters.

Comment: Does that mean that the array of strings is correctly generated and I just had a mistake in printf?

Comment: @Peter I can't tell. The output bug is blocking the ability to tell if the generated array is correct. Fix it and keep going.

Comment: Do you mean `"%.13s"`?

Answer (score 0):

Since there are 16 characters for each outer index (char [][16]),
you can use an array to print each character:

```
for(j=0;j<16;j++)
    printf("%c", cards[1][j]);
```

In this case, this prints every character of the outer index 1.